# Unable to reduce Memory footprint of Java Spring boot application in docker container after load test

Tags: java, spring-boot

Deployed the spring boot (v2.1.3) application in docker (20.10) as container and running load test to verify our application. Java version is 8

Please find the stats before load test, at time of load test and after load test.

**::: Before Load test**

ID     NAME                CPU %     MEM USAGE / LIMIT     MEM %     NET I/O           BLOCK I/O
c-id   CONTAINER_NAME    3.22%     583MiB / 31.36GiB     1.82%     24.6kB / 13.7kB   0B / 0B

**:::at time of load test**

ID     NAME                CPU %     MEM USAGE / LIMIT     MEM %     NET I/O           BLOCK I/O
c-id   CONTAINER_NAME    0.14%     1.223GiB / 31.36GiB   3.90%     47.9MB / 675MB    0B / 65.5kB

**:::after load test:::**

ID     NAME                CPU %     MEM USAGE / LIMIT     MEM %     NET I/O           BLOCK I/O
c-id   CONTAINER_NAME    0.09%     1.3GiB / 31.36GiB     4.15%     115MB / 675MB     0B / 8.77MB

Memory for the container is keep on increasing. its not all coming to normal even after completing the load test. ie. Garbage collection is not happening in docker container. (whereas garbage collection is happening when the same application deployed in Windows environment)

Are there any configuration to reduce the memory after load test.

Can anyone of you help me on that.

Comment: How much time after load test are you getting your final stats?  Garbage collection only runs periodically, so you may need to wait a bit for it to happen.  Alternatively, you could have a circular dependency on allocated objects that prevents them from being garbage collected.

Comment: waited for an hour to see memory footprint of the application

Comment: Seems like something is holding the memory in your code.  I thought it might be the circular reference issue, but I am seeing reference to those being GC'd as well in Java 8 (sorry, wasn't sure when that happened).  So it seems like something in your code is holding on to objects somehow.  A tool like VisualVM can help identify what's being held in memory, and then you can review the use of those objects in your code and make sure they are released for GC.

Comment: Garbage collection is happening when the same application deployed in Windows environment

Comment: below Problem Suspect reported from MAT tool -->  _One instance of “org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint” loaded by “org.springframework.boot.loader.LaunchedURLClassLoader @ 0xc0106240” occupies 8,446,416 (16.41%) bytes. The memory is accumulated in one instance of “java.lang.Object[]”, loaded by “<system class loader>”, which occupies 8,439,448 (16.39%) bytes._

Comment: OK, I am seeing some reference via searches to JVMs inside Docker getting different settings than you may get natively (like different GC algorithms).  To be honest, I've only run C++ apps inside Docker to date, so this was unexpected.  At this point, I'll have to defer to someone with more experience with that combination of technologies.  Sorry I couldn't be more help.

Comment: Thanks @JCampy for your immediate response to my post. came to know about circular dependency cause for GC failure. Thanks once again.